# Replace a certain line or word using php

Tags: php, numbers, filenames, cpu-word

does any one know how can u replace a certain line or word or number in a specific line of a file using php example filename below

server.cfg

```
game dm
plugins etc etc etc
ports 2345
```

so can php just update the ports number? using any form or something? would be helpfull

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php  or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. Do you have any code in place already? Can we see it?

Answer (score 0):

Following is a step by step solution with explanations for each line.

NOTE: server.cfg must be writable by PHP.  Make sure to set the permissions so that PHP can write to that file first.  Otherwise you'll get a "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error.

```
// Define the path to the file here
$myFile = '/path/to/server.cfg';

// Define the new port number here
$newPort = '12345';
$newGameMode = 'cool';
$newMaxPlayers = 120;

// Load the file
$contents = file_get_contents($myFile);

// Modify the contents
$contents = preg_replace('/(ports) (\d+)/', '$1 '.$newPort, $contents);
$contents = preg_replace('/(gamemode) ([a-z]+)/', '$1 '.$newGameMode, $contents);
$contents = preg_replace('/(maxplayers) (\d+)/', '$1 '.$newMaxPlayers, $contents);

// Overwrite the file with the new contents
file_put_contents($myFile, $contents);
```